# Vuforia Pose Matrix To UIView

Tags: c++, objective-c, vuforia

I have a project with Vuforia SDK. I want to know the frame of the object at the eaglView.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < nNumberOfObjectsFound ; i++) {
    const Vuforia::TrackableResult *trackableResult = state.getTrackableResult(i);
    const Vuforia::Matrix34F pose = trackableResult->getPose();

}
```

As it can be seen, I have the pose matrix. But I couldn't figure out how to project this matrix to the container view.

Comment: Try looking here: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/technical-how-can-i-project-target-point-screen